# is the address bus indicate the size of the address in ram?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I'm sorry for  such simple question but this question borders me. so as exp we have the address bus 20 bits.

Does this imply that the address in ram should have 20 bit as size and if the data bus has 16 bits the value in ram are code 16 bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address bus indicates the size of addressable items, including ram, bios, video ram, any I/O mapped devices, ... . The data bus indicates how many bits can be transferred at a time.

20 bits would be 1 MB of address space. However, an external chip to support extended memory could be used to allow more ram. I recall an embedded device (tape drive from the 1980's) that used an 80186, with a custom extended memory interface to support more than 1MB of ram.

Answer (score 1):

On any recent PC-like (micro) computers made the last 45 years or so, the smallest addressable unit in memory have always been the 8-bit byte.

And the the bus sizes doesn't indicate word-size or addressable range. Take for example the venerable [Motorola 68000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68000) CPU, which had an external 16-bit data bus and a 24-bit address bus. But internally it was all 32 bits, and instructions could fetch 8-, 16- or 32-bit values from memory, and all of the 32-bit address-space was addressable (even if not all was used).

Later version of the 68k CPU added full external 32-bit busses (with the [68020](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_68020)).

Comment: For some mini-computers in the 1970's the smallest normally addressable unit was a 16 bit word for most instructions, with some using an index register to access 8 bit bytes (for example, the HP 2100 series).

Comment: @rcgldr Not to mention the 36-bit systems still going strong into the 80's. That's why I sad *"PC-like"*. I.e. the *micro* computers. :)

Comment: Also, SDRAM (including current DDR4 SDRAM) transfers row and column parts of the address separately, so it can address a lot of RAM without needing a huge number of pins.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR4_SDRAM#Command_encoding shows that row addresses use 18 bits, column addresses use 10 bits.  (And the "addressable unit" is a burst of 64 bytes, which can maybe be chopped short, and in previous DDR versions could be masked).  So you could argue that it doesn't have "an address bus" in the sense that the question or this answer is talking about about.

Comment: The first PC was 1981, prior to that CP/M or similar operating systems for "home" type computers. The Pertec PCC 2000 was 8085 based small office / home computer running CP/M with 16 bit addressing, but an expanded like banked  memory interface for up to 1 MB of address space. The CP/M "bios" used the banked memory to maximize the amount of primary user RAM.